# Capybara tests fail with Timeout::Error in the first test when using Google Maps

Tags: ruby-on-rails, selenium, google-maps-api-3, rspec, capybara

I am testing with RSpec + Capybara + Selenium (Firefox).  No matter what subset of my acceptance tests I run, the first one fails (next tests do work correctly) with "reason" like this:

```
 Failure/Error: visit '/'
 Timeout::Error:
   Timeout::Error
```

My application relies on GoogleMaps and BackboneJS heavily.  When I run tests, page does not finish to load and "transferring data from maps.googleapis.com" message stays in bottom-left of Firefox window, however page looks like it loaded properly (maps and other content are present).  I've already set timeout to 60 secs to exclude any slow network problems.  And all the subsequent tests do work very fast (like proper Google scripts were fetched and are already cached).  Also when I start server in development environment and access it (`localhost:3000`) everything works fine.

Firefox 17.0.1.  Some of my gems:

```
capybara (2.0.1)
database_cleaner (0.9.1)
mongoid (3.0.13)
rspec (2.12.0)
rspec-core (2.12.1)
rspec-expectations (2.12.0)
rspec-mocks (2.12.0)
rspec-rails (2.12.0)
selenium-webdriver (2.26.0)
```

Do you have any idea why this happens and how to prevent it?

EDIT:

`spec/spec_helper.rb`:

```
# This file is copied to spec/ when you run 'rails generate rspec:install'
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'test'
require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)
require 'rspec/rails'
require 'rspec/autorun'

# Requires supporting ruby files with custom matchers and macros, etc,
# in spec/support/ and its subdirectories.
Dir[Rails.root.join("spec/support/**/*.rb")].each {|f| require f}

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include FactoryGirl::Syntax::Methods
  config.treat_symbols_as_metadata_keys_with_true_values = true
  config.infer_base_class_for_anonymous_controllers = false
  #config.order = "random"
end
```

`spec/features/features_spec_helper.rb`:

```
require_relative "../spec_helper"

require 'capybara/rspec'

Capybara.default_driver = :selenium
Capybara.default_wait_time = 60
```

EDIT2:

It used to work properly before (few weeks ago; this project was halted for that time).  <del>Could be introduced by RSpec upgrade from 2.11 to 2.12 (which I did those few weeks ago), but I've just tried to downgrade it and same things do happen.</del>  I've reverted whole codebase to the point month ago to exclude possible gem regression.  Problem still happens.

EDIT3:

I've just discovered that if I comment out the line responsible for attaching map from Google:

```
new google.maps.Map($("#map")[0], mapOptions)
```

then everything works like a charm.

EDIT4:

Source code of example application: https://github.com/skalee/capybara-google-maps-failure

Running all specs will result with Timeout::Error in the first one (at least for me).  However, all specs will pass when:

1. You remove [line which initializes Geocoder](https://github.com/skalee/capybara-google-maps-failure/blob/master/app/assets/javascripts/rmcs.js.coffee#L7) (it's not used in example app, but I use it in mine).
2. You remove [line which initializes Map](https://github.com/skalee/capybara-google-maps-failure/blob/master/app/assets/javascripts/views/offers_on_map.js.coffee#L13).
3. What surprised me most, when you provide trivial style sheet, like nothing more than that:

```
#map{ width: 600px ; height: 600px }
```

Gems are exactly the same gems as I use in my app.  There are some 3rd party scripts in `/vendor/assets`.

Comment: Could you write failing example code working with Google map at some site so we can reproduce it?

Comment: @AndreyBotalov — good point.  I've prepared a sample app by stripping my app from stuff not related to map.  I've also found two new ways to make specs passing (not fixing things though).  The problem is really odd to me…

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know Rails. After starting `rails server` I got the following exception when navigating to localhost:3000: `require_tree argument must be a directory
  (in /path_is_here/capybara-google-maps-failure/app/assets/javascripts/application.js:26)`. How can I solve it?

Comment: @AndreyBotalov My mistake, one directory was not under version control.  Fixed, thanks.  So, if you're not rails guy, to run specs just type in `bundle exec rspec`.

Comment: I've got `2 examples, 0 failures` when running it

Comment: The only thing I've changed is adding `gem 'therubyracer'` to Gemfile as I've got `Could not find a JavaScript runtime`. [Here is](http://pastebin.com/VK7P87JU) output of `bundle list`

Comment: @AndreyBotalov Thanks.  Rechecked on fresh Ruby installation and still fails for me…  This might be some race condition in Capybara which triggers or not arbitrarily depending on computer's computational power.  BTW which Ruby version (including patchlevel) do you use?

Comment: ruby-1.9.3-p286 [ x86_64 ]

Comment: Have you localized the issue? Will you post an update?

Comment: @AndreyBotalov Not at all.  I've tried with several versions of 1.9.3, including the freshest one, and results were always the same.

Comment: Have you tried cloning this repo and making `bundle`?

Comment: @AndreyBotalov: Yes, in the clean RVM gemset under several MRIs.  I've tried it without RVM too.  Always timeout error.

Comment: Try to ask in Capybara mailing list

Comment: You can also try to update Capybara version in Gemfile

Comment: @AndreyBotalov: Capybara was in her most recent version, however I updated some of its dependencies.  Nothing changed though.  I think you're right about asking on mailing list.  Thanks for your efforts.

Comment: Could it be you're being rate-limited by Google? Indicators: You definitely hit their API, others run the same code and see no timeouts, everything works when you stop hitting their API.

Comment: Looks to be working as of 20130326.  Had to bundle update selenium-webdriver for latest firefox compatibility though.

Comment: Have you tried to get capybara to save a screenshot at that point in the test? It can sometimes help. Also, try using WebMock to intercept the request and check what url is being used. Might be configured differently for test e.g. your API key might be in production.rb.

Comment: Try updating your `Capybara.default_driver = :selenium` to `Capybara.default_driver = :poltergeist`

https://github.com/jonleighton/poltergeist

Comment: You'll also eventually (if you run a lot of tests through something like guard or a continuous integration server) hit the API limits in your tests which causes all sorts of headaches.

Answer (score 1):

You should not depend on external services for your tests. Here is a strategy:

http://robots.thoughtbot.com/post/34761570235/using-capybara-to-test-javascript-that-makes-http

Comment: I concur with shadowmaru.  Don't depend on any external services for your tests.  You have no control over them.  If they change (even slightly), or go down your tests will break.  As the thoughtbot article suggested, use your environment configs to point your tests at something you **do** have control over.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing the GemFile around to have a group :production do ?

And are you loading this whole script in the proper place?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false">
```

This example is for bootstrap:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&key=YOUR_API_KEY&sensor=SET_TO_TRUE_OR_FALSE"
type="text/javascript">
</script>
```